# How to modify nested JSON with python

Tags: python, json

I need to update (CRUD) a nested JSON file using Python. To be able to call python function(s)(to update/delete/create) entires and write it back to the json file.

Here is a [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j0pi6iiww0i9fi/InputJsonfile.json?dl=0).

I am looking at [the remap](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.remap) library but not sure if this will work.

```
    {
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "group1",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "Test-Key-String",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Test-Key-Integer",
          "value": {
            "type": "Integer",
            "data": 1000
          }
        }
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "group-child",
          "properties": [
            {
              "name": "Test-Key-String",
              "value": {
                "type": "String",
                "encoding": "utf-8",
                "data": "value1"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Test-Key-Integer",
              "value": {
                "type": "Integer",
                "data": 1000
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "group2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "Test-Key2-String",
          "value": {
            "type": "String",
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "data": "value2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information. What is the problem you are having? Like Fhaab said, the existing json module lets you load JSON into a python dictionary. You can manipulate dictionaries as you see fit. Why do you feel like you need any additional library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I'm missing something in your question.  In any event, what I understand is that you want to read a json file, edit the data as a python object, then write it back out with the updated data?

Read the json file:

```
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

That creates a dictionary (given the format you've given) that you can manipulate however you want.  Assuming you want to write it out:

```
with open("data.json","w") as f:
  json.dump(data,f)
```

Comment: Read/Write is fine, My challenge is to search for a key/value pair and update it with it with a new value? That is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Well, then I think you should ask an entirely different question - how to search a dictionary for a key/value pair, and be clear - are you searching for where a key=search_key AND value=search_value?  Or are you looking for value where search_key = something in particular?  What happens when the search is "name" and you have a whole bunch of them in your data?  Give the data above, say "this is my dictionary," and then say exactly what you'd like to accomplish programatically.

Comment: Thank you @Fhaab and mad-wombat for helping me better understand my problem. The Json file has UNIQUE group names. Like group1, group2. Each Unique group has properties that contain name and values. I need to search key/value pair where groups name = group1 and name="Test-Key-Integer" and data =1000 and update it to for example 2000. The combination of group name, properties name and data value is unique. Hope this helps. Should I modifiy the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Yes, I think you should clarify the question; also be clear if you want this to really be a generic search, or given that format of data you are looking for a function that specifically looks for group name "something1" where that group has name="something2" and data=something3.  You may just need to write several functions to handle specific cases.

Comment: I will rewrite it. You comments was very very helpful. Should I make this as  an answer since you actually make it very clear and start a new question? Or just mofify the existing questions. I though you should get some points for this :)

Comment: I don't care about points; either way you want to do it is fine.